# Preposition for "on/in the internet"

Tags: preposition

*I read the articles on the internet.*
Should it be

> Ich habe die Artikel auf dem Internet gelesen.

or

> Ich habe die Artikel im Internet gelesen.

Comment: Isn't it "on the internet" in English, and Germans are those who say "in the internet", because they apply the German preposition?!

Comment: oder "im *Netz*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are talking about that exact sentence, the preposition of choice is *"im"*:

> Ich habe den Artikel **im** Internet / Web / Netz gelesen.

on the other hand, if you are talking about a specific website, it's *"auf"*:

> Ich habe den Artikel **auf** der BILD-Seite gelesen.

But if you are talking about a newspaper (a "real" one, not a digital) it's *"in"*:

> Ich habe den Artikel **in** der Zeitung / [Zeitungsname] gelesen.

Answer (score 3):

On the internet is `Im Internet`. Some of my german friends say `Im Netz`.

> Ich habe den Artikel `im Internet` gelesen.

Or

> Ich habe den Artikel `im Netz` gelesen.

In German, it's `in the internet` not `on the internet`.